# Error in LSTM during testing

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

My data is of 68871 x 43, where the features are in the column no. 1-42 and label in column no. 43

My keras LSTM code for classification of the data is

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# convert an array of values into a dataset matrix
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-look_back-1):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        #if i==0
        # print len(a)
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 43])
    return numpy.array(dataX), numpy.array(dataY)
# fix random seed for reproducibility
numpy.random.seed(7)
# load the dataset
#dataframe = pandas.read_csv('international-airline-passengers.csv', usecols=[1], engine='python', skipfooter=3)
dataset = numpy.loadtxt("Source.txt", delimiter=" ")
#dataset = dataframe.values
#dataset = dataset.astype('float32')
# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
# split into train and test sets
train_size = int(len(dataset) * 0.67)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size,:], dataset[train_size:len(dataset),:]
# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 1
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX = numpy.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], 1, trainX.shape[1]))
testX = numpy.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], 1, testX.shape[1]))
# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(3, input_dim=look_back))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, nb_epoch=1, batch_size=1)
score, acc = model.evaluate(testX, testY)
print('Test score:', score)
print('Test accuracy:', acc)
```

I am getting this error during testing time [image]

Please help resolve this, many thanks in advance

Comment: Hey. Is your problem solved? Consider validating answer or giving further details.

Answer (score 3):

I think that your problem is that `model.evaluate(testX, testY)` is only returning one value.

Your error message tells you that `numpy.float64` isn't iterable. What it means it that `model.evaluate(testX, testY)` returns a `float64` and thus, you cannot put it return value into two variables `score, acc`.

It would be like doing:

```
def single_return():
    return np.float64(10)
a, b = single_return()
```

(Note that this code will raise the exact same error).

I would then suggest, both to fix it now, but also as a quite good practice for the future to always return into a single variable, then to split. It make error message more clear, as only line having problem will be the affectation, not the `evaluation` one.

Hope it helps.
`pltrdy`